# Set (EduRoster.Read.All, EduRoster.ReadWrite.All) Application Permissions

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am working with School Data Sync(SDS) and Azure Active Directory with Microsoft Graph API with a custom Web App that is being developed.
I require read and write to the SDS objects (class, school etc) created by a SDS sync profile.

Reading https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/educationroot_list_schools
and related documentation - I can potentially achieve the above.

Yet the required permissions (
EduRoster.Read.All, EduRoster.ReadWrite.All 
)
are not available to be set in the Active Directory Portal (using application > Settings > Required Permissions > Microsoft Graph)

How can I perhaps set the required permissions, perhaps by some other means or through the portal, for my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you posted is right. The documentation shows Permissions's Name directly. Acutally, if you use v2 endpoint application in [Microsoft App Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) to choose permissions, you will see these permissions directly.

**For this case, the permissions you saw in the Azure portal is the permission's Display String.**

*For Example:*

Application permissions: `EduRoster.ReadWrite.All` 's Display string is `Read and write the organization's roster`.

So, you can add these permissions for your scenario:

[image]

You can see details about Microsoft Graph Permissions Reference in [this documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#education-permissions).

Comment: Darn i did not make that connection in the naming and description. Thankyou. Also should have clarified I was using v2 endpoint and the MSGraph API for PHP

Comment: @JakoKotzé . If this answer was helpful , please mark it as answer so that we can help more people. Thanks!